# How to Find The Starting Position of the Nth Match of A Regular Expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently learning about how regular expressions work in Python, and so far have found everything very digestible.

I know that you can find the starting position of a match object in Python using the .start function.

I know that you can retrieve a list of total matches (in string form), using the re.findAll() function.

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to find the starting position of the nth element?

So far I can only think of one way to do it, which is a hand-coded solution, where I iteratively split the string by each match up to n, counting the total characters as I go:

```
def getNthStartingPosOfPattern(pattern, text, n):
    all_matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        this_split = text.split(all_matches[i])
        result += len(this_split[0])
        new_start_pos = result + len(all_matches[i])
        text = text[new_start_pos:]
    return result


text = "09834 82 Monkey-wtf 2323, 8371853 Monkey-wtf 244, 39082348 Monkey-ftw 827,2  Monkey-lbj 2,24857 Monkey-kkk,oo293 Monkey-iij 55, 273 Monkey-eif 7,22288888 Monkey-abc"
pattern = r'Monkey-[a-z]{3}'
result = getNthStartingPosOfPattern(pattern, text, 5)
print(result)
```

This seems to work but seems laborious, and prone to edge-case issues. Does the Python library give us a simpler way to do this that I just haven't understood?

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`MatchObject.start()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) that you can access with the help of [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

Here, you can obtain the starting position of the 5th match like this:

```
import re
def getNthStartingPosOfPattern(pattern, text, n):
    for i,x in enumerate(re.finditer(pattern, text)):
        if i == n-1:
            return x.start()

text = "09834 82 Monkey-wtf 2323, 8371853 Monkey-wtf 244, 39082348 Monkey-ftw 827,2  Monkey-lbj 2,24857 Monkey-kkk,oo293 Monkey-iij 55, 273 Monkey-eif 7,22288888 Monkey-abc"
pattern = r'Monkey-[a-z]{3}'
print(getNthStartingPosOfPattern(pattern, text, 5))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/bInxIC)

Comment: Great response. I would move the [4] to [n] and turn it into a function. Does the re.finditer() do yields behind the scenes?

Comment: It *yields the MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string*. Turned into a `def`.

Comment: As per @JeffMandell edit, I think the updated function will return the result quicker than using comprehension since it won't have to collect all matches before.